# nodejs loop array to create object

Tags: arrays, node.js, each

I try to create a

html element for each element in an array but It doesn't work can you help me ?

my node js code :

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    // if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!")
    con.query( 'SELECT * FROM `commentairesapplicationscommunautaire` ', function (error, results, fields) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            var zeuzryueartt = results[i].contenu
            console.log(zeuzryueartt)
            res.end('<p> '+ zeuzryueartt +'  </p>')
        }
    });
});
```

this code looks like : `<p> rrr </p>`

But is wrong for my case

Thanks

Comment: Where is `res` coming from? Is `con.connect` inside of a node handler? Regardless, you can only use `res.end/send/json` once per callback. You'll have to concatenate these into a single variable and send that back

Comment: I want this : <p> rrr </p> <p> with a another  </p> <p> <p> etc </p>

Comment: @SterlingArcher the code is not complete you know

Comment: I have try but it doesn't work : like var htmlcode = '<p> ' + zeuzryueartt  + ' </p>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending the response stream on the very first step. You need to only call `end` once you built entire response html.

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    // if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!")
    con.query( 'SELECT * FROM `commentairesapplicationscommunautaire` ', function (error, results, fields) {
       const entireHTML = results.map(result => `<p>${result.contenu}</p>`).join('')
       res.end(entireHTML)
    });
});
```